# Will sticking plastic (PLA) in a usb port cause a short?

Tags: usb, short-circuit

**The problem**: I want to mount a webcam to the top of my monitor (monitor is in portrait orientation). The webcam I have on hand has an awkward clamping mechanism, and I'm struggling to get it to mount sturdily. I don't want it pressing against my screen, as it blocks the view of the top of my screen and could potentially damage the screen.

**The solution**: Taking advantage of the 2 usb ports along the top edge of the monitor, 3D print a simple webcam holder using PLA that slots into the 2 USB ports. This would provide a place to mount the webcam and also elevate the webcam so that the screen is not blocked.

**Potential problems?**:

1. Short out the monitor - based on what I'm reading, PLA has a high resistance, so this is unlikely. I can use a multimeter to test my specific filaments resistance
2. Get broken plastic stuck in the usb port - annoying but I could fish it out with the monitor off/unplugged.
3. Waste of 2 USB ports - not a problem for me.

I acknowledge that this is not the most elegant solution, but it is something I could do right away to solve my problem. Would this work?

Comment: @SamGibson, have voted to close as off-topic. This is on the use of electronic equipment, not remotely electronics design.

Comment: PLA is kind of brittle, you run the risk of the anchor snapping off. consider using a stronger plastic like ABS, Polycarbonate, or acrylic,  or  soldering a steel bracket to a USB plug.

Comment: I would argue that the applicability of a material as an insulator(the essential question here) is *at least* loosely affiliated with electrical engineering.

Comment: Does your monitor not have a back? I would use 3M command adhesive strips on the back of the monitor.

Comment: @TonyM - Hi, I respect your view on that. Since the question in the title is about an electrical property, I decided that community voting (rather than my mod "close hammer"!) would be a suitable way to decide which side of the line this question "falls". If it was much more about 3D printing, then I agree it would likely cross the "off-topic" line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PLA will not cause a short, but some unusual formulations of PLA that include metal particles may be risky -- they are marketed as either "conductive PLA" or be designed with glossy, metallic finishes. For example, [this PLA](https://www.blackmagic3d.com/Conductive-p/grphn-pla.htm) has a resistivity of 0.6 ohm-cm, which can easily lead to a short circuit in a USB port. It's also clearly marked as a conductive product. (as a side-note, these are also abrasive to extruders and will cause extruder wear unless you have one made with specialized materials/coatings)

From the perspective of electrical design, USB is already designed to tolerate pullups and pulldowns of around 15 kilo-ohms, as well as easily tolerating similar load resistances between VBUS and ground (which lead to current on the order of mA flowing). Meanwhile, PLA that doesn't include conductive filler is [much more resistive](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/4821/62) by orders of magnitude.

There are further concerns with the brittleness; if you do print it, go for a solid infill to avoid the part snapping off inside the port, avoid weak points at any corners, and avoid mechanical loads with large moments. The full details of this involve slicer settings and are beyond the scope of this site.